# How to prevent playing sound during Window is opening?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl1">
        <TabItem Header="General"/>
        <TabItem Header="Security" />
        <TabItem Header="Details" />
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb.net

```
Class MainWindow
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectionChanged
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play()
End Sub
End Class
```

I want to play sound when User clicks every TabItem.

The codes above play sound during Window is opening which I dont want.

So, how to prevent playing sound during Window is opening?

Comment: You are going to drive your user bat-crazy with this code.  If he wants to hear a sound then he'll set it up with Control Panel > Sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the property `IsLoaded` in `Window`, that can be used for that purpose.

You could check for the value of `IsLoaded` to determine whether to play the sound or not (it may well be that there are syntactic errors, my VB.NET is not that good ;) )

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub TabControl1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectionChanged
        If IsLoaded Then
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The first selection of the first tab should occur before `Loaded` is called, hence `IsLoaded` should be false and no sound should be played.